# Refactor local variable to a field?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I create a class variable from a local variable in JetBrains IDE's (like IntelliJ, PyCharm, WebStorm, etc.)?

For example, transform this:

[image: Before]

Into this:

[image: After]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Or: *Refactor* > *Extract* > *Field*.

Comment: You can also use refactor menu (ctrl+t or cmd+t)

Comment: Unfortunately, ctrl + t does not work for me in Intellij.

Comment: Keyboard shortucts depend on what Keymap you are using (`Settings/Preferences | Keymap`) and therefore they can be different depending on OS used. That's why you should specify the menu path first. You can also check what shortcut that menu item / action has (there in menu or in Keymap settings) and adjust it if needed.